# declare a variable without registering it to the environment

Tags: r, scope, environment-variables

In some R script, I use some dummy variable in a for loop.

The variable has no purpose itself, so I don't need it recorded at all.

For instance :

```
database = read.csv("data/somefile.csv")    
for (i in 1:ncol(database)) {
    name <- names(database)[i]
    if (name %in% some_vector) {
        label(database[, .i]) <- some_function(databas$somecolumn)
    }
}
```

In R Studio, the "Global Environement" tab keeps track of variables `i` and `name` (and give it the last value it had), although they have no usefulness at all.

Is there any elegant way to declare my value so it is not tracked in the global environment ?

Comment: `.x = 2` works. You might run into new problems, though, like `rm(list = ls())` missing it.

Comment: An easy way would be to wrap your loop in a function, so the dummy variable exists only in its execution environment, which is discarded immediately after. A harder way would be to use `assign()` but you would risk going down the [rabbit hole](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/)

Comment: @Frank That it ! Thank you sir ! I can't really see the problems I could run into, but there is no one in the script I'm working on.

Comment: @Frank you can post as an answer so I can accept it. If you could explain a bit about Roland's comment on Hong Ooi answer, it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide objects from RStudio's object explorer, you can prefix with `.` like

```
.x = 2
```

*Downsides.* This still creates `.x` and keeps it in memory, where it might take up space or accidentally be used again after you've forgotten about it. It also hides from the standard "clear workspace" command `rm(list = ls())`. See `?ls` for a way of handling this.

---

*Aside.* Generally, I would not create any variables like this, instead wrapping any operation involving temporary objects in a function as @Aurèle suggested and not leaning too heavily on what RStudio's object browser shows me.

The only case so far where I've used dot-prefixed objects is for interactive use in a function, like:

```
f = function(x, y, debug.obj = FALSE){
  dx = dim(x)
  dy = dim(y)
  if (!(length(dx) == 2 && length(dy) == 2 && dx[2] == dy[1])){
    if (debug.obj){
      .debug.f <<- list(dx = dx, dy = dy)
      stop("Dims don't match. See .debug.f")
    }
    stop("Dims don't match.")
  }
  x %*% y
}  

# example usage
f(matrix(1,1,1), matrix(2,2,2), debug.obj = TRUE)
# Error in f(matrix(1, 1, 1), matrix(2, 2, 2), debug.obj = TRUE) : 
#   Dims don't match. See .debug.f
.debug.f
# $dx
# [1] 1 1
# 
# $dy
# [1] 2 2
```

Even this might be a bad idea, though.

Answer (score 5):

Use `local` for all your workspace hygiene needs.

```
foo <- local({
    x <- 0
    for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars))
        x <- x + mtcars$mpg[i]
    x
})
```

`foo` now contains the result of the calculation, and the temporary variables `i` and `x` are discarded.

Comment: This is neat and clean, but quite an overkill in my loop. I'm going with the `.x` way of @Frank

Comment: @DanChaltiel The variable still exists in the global environment with Frank's solution. It just isn't displayed.

Comment: `local` sometimes does more than that, e.g., with `f = local({y = 10; function(x) x + y})`, `y` is not discarded. And in RStudio's object explorer, this is obfuscated... though that seems more like a reason not to trust that tool.